# UIAlertView + TextField = Error?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I am making a application so data can be saved to a Table View and I wanted to use the UIAlertView Controller in a way so people can use it to create a new Cell (task) but I know how to make a textField in a UIAlertView but how do use the textField data and use it in a UIAlertView Action button!

```
@IBAction func addNewTask() {

        var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add A New Task", message: "Add The Correct Information To Add A New Task!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        // Create the actions
        var Exit = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Task", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")


        }
        var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Exit App", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("User Exited The App!")
            exit(2)

        }

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
            // Here you can configure the text field (eg: make it secure, add a placeholder, etc)

        }

        // Add the actions
        alertController.addAction(Exit)

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present the controller
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

This is the code but how can I use the data from the `alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigureationHandler` and put it in the `Exit` Action! So the main thing I want this to do just know is when the user types in the textbox and clicks Exit a label will change to that text from the textField but without using a viewController! I am using Swift, Xcode 6.3.1

Thanks,

George Barlow

p.s. Sorry for the longwinded question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UIAlertAction` called `Exit` (btw, you should consider changing the name to something like `exit` or `exitAction`), you can access the `UITextField` and its contents in the following way:

```
// Create the actions
var Exit = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Task", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    UIAlertAction in
    let loginTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as! UITextField
    let inputText = loginTextField.text
    println("The input text is: \(inputText)")
    NSLog("OK Pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

" . .. you can also add text fields to the alert interface. The alert controller lets you provide a block for configuring your text fields prior to display. The alert controller maintains a reference to each text field so that you can access its value later." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController

There is a textfield property on the UIAlertViewController that you can access.

```
alertController.textFields
```

The text fields are added to this array in the same order that you added them to the alert controller.

Inside your completion for the exit action:

```
UITextField *taskTextField = alertController.textFields.firstObject
```

*Edit: in swift:

```
if let taskTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as! UITextField {
    let taskText = taskTextField.text
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
        var mytextField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            addNewTask()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        func addNewTask() {
            var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add A New Task", message: "Add The Correct Information To Add A New Task!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            // Create the actions
            var Exit = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Task", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("OK Pressed")

                self.myLabel.text = self.mytextField.text


            }
            var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Exit App", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("User Exited The App!")
                exit(2)

            }

            alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
                // Here you can configure the text field (eg: make it secure, add a placeholder, etc)

                self.mytextField = textField
            }

            // Add the actions
            alertController.addAction(Exit)

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            // Present the controller
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }
```